# Why won't NPM perform a proper install when it previously used to work?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting this error whenever I try to run npm install --save:

ERROR in ../node_modules/parse/lib/browser/LocalDatastore.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve `@babel/runtime-corejs3/core-js-stable/array/from' in '/Users/danieljones/Documents/Btown-Rides/btown-rides-parse-dashboard/node_modules/parse/lib/browser' @ ../node_modules/parse/lib/browser/LocalDatastore.js 7:35-94 @ ../node_modules/parse/lib/browser/Parse.js @ ../node_modules/parse/index.js @ ./dashboard/Data/Browser/Browser.react.js @ ./dashboard/Dashboard.js @ ./dashboard/index.js`

My parse dashboard used to work, but now whenever I try to deploy to Heroku or install npm, then it just will keep throwing this error. I know that it's not deploying to Heroku because the npm packages can't install properly. I feel like this is probably a problem on my local machine or somehow my npm is messed up. But, I can't figure it out. I even forked a perfectly clean copy of the parse-dashboard and tried to run npm install --save. I still get the exact same error.

Comment: this one https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard ? In the console, type `npm --version`. What version do you have?

Comment: If you’re trying to install dependencies to a newly cloned repo you don’t need `--save` option.

Comment: npm --version is 6.12.0
and yes github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard is the one. @Gosha_Fighten